# Why is my instance variable always Nil in my Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5, instance-variables

The problem that I'm having is that any instance variables that I declare in my show function of Charges Controller, appears as nil in the view. If I set an instance variable to a number, it doesn't even appear in the view. My home function works perfectly with instance variables.

This is my Controller with the Home and Show functions:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

def home
    @products = Product.all
end

def show
    @product = Product.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

This is my View for the Show function(show.html.erb):

```
<h1>Product Details</h1>

<h3> <%= @product.name %> </h3>
<h4> <%= @product.price %> </h4>
<h5> <%= @product.description %> </h5>
```

This is my view for the Home function that contains the button that directs to the show page(home.html.erb)

```
<h1>Products</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <br>

   <p> <%= product.name %>: $<%= product.price %> </p>
   <p> <%= product.description %> </p>

   <%= button_to "Product Details", charge_path(product.id), :method => "get" %>
   <br>

<%end%>
```

[error message I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceERk.png)

Comment: Try using the `find_by!` method which will throw an exception if no product with that identifier could be found. You can `rescue_from` this to present an error. Assuming any database action succeeded is usually a mistake.

Comment: But even if it exists, such as Product.first. That works if I set that to an instance variable in my home function, but not the show function. Still will show nil. I will use find_by! instead though, thank you.

Comment: Are you confusing `@products` with `@product`? The only method executing on show will be the one that populates `@product`. If the `show` action successfully populates `@product` then it will work in the view. If it doesn't, either some other bit of code reassigned the value or that code somehow didn't get executed in the first place.

Comment: not sure if you have a preference towards using `find_by` here, but since you're using `id` as the parameter, try using `find(params[:id])` instead, to see what error it's throwing. By default, if `find_by` doesn't find what you're passing in, it simply returns `nil`. `find` on the other hand will tell you what's wrong, perhaps `RecordNotFound`?

Comment: @iamjhu Still getting nil even if I use `find(params[:id])`

Comment: what is your route for the show action ? `bundle exec rake routes | grep charges#show` ?

Comment: @sa77   `/charges/:id` The id in the url does change to the correct id number for each product

Comment: you probably should add id: on your button_to tag `<%= button_to "Product Details", charge_path(id: product.id), :method => "get" %>`

Comment: @sa77 I added your changes, but no difference in the output.

Comment: You should add `p instance_variables` at the end of your `show` method, and `<%= instance_variables.inspect %>` as the first line of your show template. Then, compare the (logged) output of the controller to the displayed output in the view and ensure they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

`find_by` method returns `nil` if it does not find the record. So that means the product id(`params[:id]`) you searching in your `Product` model is not found.

You can check it manually in the rails console.
Type `rails c` in your terminal then try the bellow code

```
Product.find_by(id: the_id_you_want_to_search)
```

Alternatively you can use `find` method. It raises an exception when it does not find the record.

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: I've checked rails console and the products do exist

Comment: Then may be `params[:id]` of your `show` action getting wrong value somehow. Bdw, is it solved?

Comment: Nope, not solved yet. Still working on it. Still lost

Comment: Could you provide the error message as an screenshot?

Comment: No problem, I've added a screenshot in my original post

Comment: Could you check this url `http://localhost:3000/charges/product_id` in your browser?. If you running the server other then 3000 port then place the your port instead of 3000 and place an available product id in`product_id` of the url.

Comment: Yes, that's the url that I have. `http://localhost:3000/charges/2` 
I have 4 products. All give the same error.

Comment: May be you can try by restarting the rails server and one thing if you use `find` method instead of  `find_by` something like this code `@product = Product.find(params[:id])` in your `show` action ... then what is the error it is showing?

Answer (score 0):

By default ,its always `find by id`,So kindly use only..

```
def show
    @product = Product.find params[:id]
end
```

Moreover,you can check in rails console using `rails c` to verify that the record is present with that id using,for example `Product.find 18`.
Also check the url which should match with your routes..for example..`/users/:id` for `get` request Only mapped to `users#show` action.

Get local copy of your routes using `rake routes > path.text` and use it as reference

Comment: Did you tried verifying the same id in rails console as i mentioned.Also verify your routes entry too.

Comment: Yes, a product exists for the id in rails console, my route is `charges#show` and `/charges/:id` for `get` request

Comment: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

In your home.html.erb try change this

```
<%= button_to "Product Details", charge_path(product.id), :method => "get" %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Product Details", charge_path(product.id) %>
```

Then if it does not work, try to raise the params or the instance in your show method

```
def show
  raise params.inspect
  @product = Product.find params[:id]
end
```

or

```
def show
  @product = Product.find params[:id]
  raise @product.inspect
end
```

Those were some simple ways to check whats happening in your code.

Comment: Nothing different is shown with these changes. Still the same error page, saying "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: did you raise the instance in the controller? It should raise the params or instance. It seems there is a routing error. You are not getting into the show method.

Comment: Yes, I added `raise @product.inspect` too but no difference. In my routing I have `resources :charges` so it creates the `show` route automatically. Not sure where it's getting messed up

Comment: it is not messed up, maybe your just pointing incorrect paths, can you comment the output of `rake routes | grep charge` ? and also, is your view files under the correct directory? in this case, views/charges/show.html.erb ?

Comment: GET    /                                  charges#home
charges        GET    /charges(.:format)       charges#index
                     POST   /charges(.:format)      charges#create
new_charge GET    /charges/new(.:format)   charges#new
edit_charge  GET    /charges/:id/edit(.:format) charges#edit
charge          GET    /charges/:id(.:format)     charges#show
                     PATCH  /charges/:id(.:format)   charges#update
                     PUT    /charges/:id(.:format)    charges#update
                     DELETE /charges/:id(.:format)  charges#destroy